# for loop syntax in python

Tags: python

Sorry this might be a very stupid question. But I did have bug with the following naming.

```
for i in my_hash_dict:      #1st
   for y in my_hash_dict[i]:
      do something with i ...

for i in my_hash_dict:       #2nd
      do something with i...
```

the problem is seems like if I reusing i this name in 2nd for loop , it "seems" will cost my program not running correctly. If I change the i in 2nd for loop, then seems everything working fine...

Maybe it just some of my stupid typo or something else cause this problem.

But I hope experiecned python programmer can give me some answers... Thankyou

Comment: You are missing a `:` at the end of the `for` line. Please post some real Python code.

Comment: sorry, im really a super big noob to python... fixed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the 'i' element as index.
Probably this code will work for you:

```
for element in my_hash_dict:     
    for y in element:
        do something with y ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a syntax issue as Tichodroma mentioned, take a look at this [documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm), your example looks fine you just need to add the `:` if you still get an unexpected output please post it.